# Finding substring between the first parentheses pair in a string using JavaScript Regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

Let's say I have a string:

```
var str1 = '(The cat (goes (meow)))'
```

I want to get `The cat (goes (meow))` from this, which is inside the first pair of parentheses.

Which regex can I use to get this?

Another example:

```
var str2 = 'The cat (goes (meow))'
```

Now I want to get `goes (meow)`.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: For a regex specifically you will require a recursive regex for nested parenthesis. Javascript's support for recursive regex's is limited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex `/\((.*)\)/` to match everything inside the outer most pair of parentheses. Try the code below.

```js
var regEx = /\((.*)\)/;

var str1 = '(The cat (goes (meow)))';
var res = str1.match(regEx);
console.log(res[1]);

var str2 = 'The cat (goes (meow))';
var res = str2.match(regEx);
console.log(res[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `indexOf` & `lastIndexOf` to get the first `(` & last `)`. The use substring to get the text in between these indexes

```js
var str1 = '(The cat (goes (meow)))';
var str2 = 'The cat (goes (meow))';

function getSubstring(str) {
  var firstOpenBracket = str.indexOf('(');
  var firstClosingBracket = str.lastIndexOf(')');
  var getValue = str.substring(firstOpenBracket + 1, firstClosingBracket);
  console.log(getValue)
}

getSubstring(str1);
getSubstring(str2)
```